# Converting depth_image from Kinect to OpenCV classic format(IplImage) for displaying

Tags: opencv, kinect, openni, depth-buffer, iplimage

I am working with OpenCV2.4.5 and OpenNI2.0 (with SDK Kinect 1.6) on visual studio 2012. I try to develop an application of gaze tracking, for that i use "Kinect sensor" to get image_data and i want to process this ilage on OpenCV (Features extraction and machine learning).

If any one has an example or or a good tuto, it will be very helpful for me.

Best regards.

Comment: c-api is not 'classic', but deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

why not start with an [opencv sample here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/samples/cpp/openni_capture.cpp) ?

Comment: Thank you for the link, but i am not undestanding why my code is not working :' VideoCapture video(CV_CAP_OPENNI);'
  cvNamedWindow("Kinect",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  for(;;)
   {
  Mat depthMap;
  Mat rgbImage;

  video.grab();

  video.retrieve(depthMap,CV_CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP);
  video.retrieve(rgbImage,CV_CAP_OPENNI_BGR_IMAGE);

  imshow("kinect",rgbImage);'

Comment: code in comments is unreadable, please edit your question instead. also, what goes wrong ?

Comment: I am sorry for the code, i am new user here. The problem is that : "imshow" doesn't work with the image retrieved from the kinnect by this routine (video.retrieve())!